# Importing individual components in a React app

Tags: reactjs, import

I'm curious about something I read in the `react-bootstrap` documentation:

> You should import individual components like: `react-bootstrap/Button` rather than the entire library. Doing so pulls in only the specific components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of code you end up sending to the client.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#importing

Sounds good. But a library like `react-bootstrap` you could be importing  different components. Would you have to add several `import` in component or is there a more efficient way to specify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you would have to import each component individually, unless you import the full library.

```
import { Button, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

or

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert';
```

Comment: Yeah, the first method is what I have been doing. But if the latter can "significantly reduce" the amount of code being sent to the client, and thus speed up the application, it is worth exploring. Just seems like having a dozen or so lines is bad practice though. (Although if the components are built well, there probably shouldn't be a need for more than a handful... maybe).

Comment: You could import them all into one file and export them back where you need them
 `Import {Button, Alert} from './MyCustomFile'`